# FreeIPA in LXD/LXC containers - cannot switch user

Tags: linux, lxc, freeipa

The Setup consists of one FreeIPA-Server and one Client, which both reside in unprivileged LXD-Containers on the same Host. Both containers and the host machine run Ubuntu 16.04. All Settings are basically FreeIPA defaults, as generated by `ipa-server-install` or `ipa-client-install`, respectively.

It is not possible to switch to a user that was created in the FreeIPA directory:

`# su testuser
setgid: Invalid argument`

`# sudo -s -u testuser
sudo: unable to change to runas gid: Invalid argument
sudo: unable to change to runas gid: Invalid argument
root is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported`

(root is in sudoers and is able to do the command above with local users.)

*testuser* is a valid User within the Realm, is able to `kinit`, and is also recognized by both systems:
`# id testuser
uid=161200001(testuser) gid=161200001(testuser) groups=161200001(testuser)`

sudo does not seem to produce any relevant entries in auth.log, su however does:

> su[1887]: Successful su for testuser by root
>
> su[1887]: + ??? root:testuser
>
> su[1887]: bad group ID `161200001' for user `testuser': Invalid argument

A Google search only brought up cygwin+sshd issues for the invalid argument error, which seemed unfitting. The ID range picked by FreeIPA is under Linux' UID limit of 2^32, even with the container offset of 100.000. What could be the problem here? Any ideas where to dig further?

**Edit 1:** The same Server/Client constellation works fine in two VirtualBox-machines.

**Edit 2:** I think I narrowed the cause down to the IPA client in a container, the issue persists when running against an IPA server outside LXD.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it! Sharing the solution, just in case somebody else with the same problem stumbles upon this thread.

In the default configuration, LXD / the Host-System does not allocate enough UIDs/GIDs to its containers, so that you cannot effectively become a user with an ID as high as picked by FreeIPA randomly.

The files `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` have entries that read `root:100000:65536`, which note the IDs that LXD will effectively use at the time of writing. Host UIDs/GIDs in the range of 100000-165536 get mapped to container IDs from 0-65536. The container, trying to use ID 161200001 in my case, is far over that boundary.

Based on this article https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/10/30/nested-containers-in-lxd/ , I modified the mapped IDs, and specified which IDs FreeIPA may use. Changes to the sub*id-files might only work before initialising a container.

Specifically, this config worked:

> LXD Host:
>
> `/etc/subuid:` root:5000000:2500000
>
> `/etc/subgid:` root:5000000:2500000
>
> LXD Container with FreeIPA-Server:
>
> initialise the server with `ipa-server-install --idstart=1000000 --idmax=2000000`

Here, the directory IDs range from 1.000.000 - 2.000.000, whereas the client has 2.500.000 IDs available. Due to the offset of 5.000.000, the host may also join that FreeIPA directory. Adjust the numbers as desired, YMMV.